# TailwindCSS styling applies to one React Component list but not the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

Hello I have two cards but one of them is not applying it's TailwindCSS stuff to the divs at all.  I hope it's just some stupid error because I'm kind of scratching my head.

[image: Right cards not getting styling]

Is the relevant incorrect code:

Where it's being rendered in the index page:
Dashboard.tsx:

```
<div className="flex flex-col border border-red-700">
                {orders.map(
                        ({ id, managerId, invoiceNumber, companyName, contact, partNumbers, partNames, quote, locationOnServer, reportType, createdAt }) => {
                            return (
                                <WorkOrderCard  id={id} managerId={managerId} invoiceNumber={invoiceNumber} companyName={companyName} contact={contact} partNumbers={partNumbers} partNames={partNames} quote={quote} locationOnServer={locationOnServer} reportType={reportType} createdAt={createdAt} timesheet={[]} />
                            )
                        }
                    )}
```

And here is the component definition WorkOrderCard.tsx:

```
export default function WorkOrderCard(props) {
    const { id, managerId, invoiceNumber, companyName, contact, partNumbers, partNames, quote, locationOnServer, reportType, createdAt, timesheet} = props;
    const [manager, setManager] = React.useState<string>("");
    useEffect(() => {
        if (manager !== undefined) {
            const res = fetch("/api/users/get/" + managerId, {
                method: 'GET',
            }).then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    res.json().then((manager) => {
                        setManager(manager.name);
                    })

                } else {
                    console.log("There was an error fetching the ticket");
                    // setErrorMessage(res.statusText)
                }
            })
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        /* Trying to draw an outline around the div but It doesn't appear */
        <div className="flex outline outline-red-600">
            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div className="flex flex-row">
                    <div className="flex">Invoice #{invoiceNumber}</div>
                    <div className="flex">{companyName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Contact:</strong> {contact || 'N/A'}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Part Numbers:</strong>{' '}
                        {partNumbers.length > 0 ? partNumbers.join(', ') : 'N/A'}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Part Names:</strong>{' '}
                        {partNames.length > 0 ? partNames.join(', ') : 'N/A'}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Quote:</strong> ${quote}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Location on Server:</strong> {locationOnServer}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Report Type:</strong> {reportType}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Created At:</strong> {createdAt.toString()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-text">
                        <strong>Manager:</strong> {manager}
                    </div>
                    {timesheet.length > 0 && (
                        <div className="card-text">
                            <strong>Time Sheet:</strong>
                            <ul>
                                {timesheet.map((time) => (
                                    <li key={time.id}>
                                        {new Date(time.date).toLocaleString()} - {new Date(time.date).setHours(new Date(time.date).getHours() + time.hours).toLocaleString()}
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The working code is called like this Dashboard.tsx:

```
<div className="flex flex-col  justify-evenly border border-red-700">
                {tickets.map(
                        ({ id, creator, broken_item, issue_desc, loc, prio, active, creatorName, createdAt }) => {
                            return (
                                <TicketGUI className="m-3" id={id} creator={creator} broken_item={broken_item} issue_desc={issue_desc} loc={loc} prio={prio} active={active} name={creatorName} createdAt={createdAt} />
                            )
                        }
                    )}
                <div className="flex justify-between m-2">
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        ticketPageSelect(currentSession.user.id, tickets[0].id, setTickets, true, pageSize)
                    }} className="justify-end px-4 py-2 text-sm text-blue-100 bg-blue-500 rounded shadow">
                        Prev
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        ticketPageSelect(currentSession.user.id, tickets[tickets.length - 1].id, setTickets, false, pageSize)
                    }} className="justify-end px-4 py-2 text-sm text-blue-100 bg-blue-500 rounded shadow">
                        Next
                    </button>
                </div>
         </div>
```

And here is the working component TicketGUI.tsx:

```
export default function TicketGUI(props){
    const handlePress = async (e) => {
        Router.push('/tickets/'+props.id)     
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg p-2 m-3 outline outline-blue-300">
            <div className="flex  ">
                <img
                    className="object-cover h-12"
                    src={props.active ? "/inprocess.png" : "/fixed.png"}
                    alt="image"
                />
                <h1 className=" ml-2 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
                        {props.broken_item}  - TicketID: {props.id}
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div className="p-4">
                
                <p className="mb-2 leading-normal">
                    {props.issue_desc}
                </p>
                <div className="flex w-full">
                    <button onClick={handlePress} className="px-4 py-2 text-sm text-blue-100 bg-blue-500 rounded shadow">
                        View Details
                    </button>
                    
                    <p className="p-2">
                        {format(new Date(props.createdAt),'MM/dd/yyyy')}
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated Chat-GPT suggested this but no dice and I factored out className from props:

> It looks like the problem is that the className prop is being passed
> to the component but it is not being used to apply classes to the
> elements within the component. In the code you posted, the className
> prop is only being used to specify the component's own class, but it
> is not being used to apply classes to the elements within the
> component.
>
> To fix this, you can either use the className prop to specify the
> classes for each element within the component, or you can use the
> className prop to specify the classes for the component itself and
> then use the class prop to specify the classes for the elements within
> the component.
>
> For example, you could change this line:
>
> ```
> <div className={className}>
> ```
>
> to this:
>
> ```
> <div className={className}>
>     <div className='flex flex-col'>
>         <div className="flex flex-row">
>             ...
>         </div>
>         <div className="card-body">
>             ...
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

[image: dev tools screenshot]

Comment: Did you just answer youself in the question?

Comment: Nope @Konrad I tried that solution that i got from chat gpt and It didn't work.  Or Maybe I'm just misunderstanding what It's trying to tell me. Try it out yourself it's actually pretty sick https://chat.openai.com/chat

Comment: Open dev tools and see if the classes are present in html and see if css is being applied

Comment: They aren't for the WorkOrderCards https://imgur.com/i7lUbb9 but they are for TicketGUI

Comment: There `flex flex-col border border-red-700` are clearly applied. You then have classes like `card-body` which aren't a part of tailwind

Comment: That was the answer I needed to remove the class names, I tried that at first but my NextJS server didn't recompile correctly when I saved the WorkOrderCard.tsx and I had to remove everything then stop the server and restart and it fixed it thank you